# How to get current day of the week in vimscript?

Tags: python, vim, dynamic

I have recently started using Vim and I have been loving it!! One thing that I am using it for right now is a planning vim document (to plan out my day). I have a school schedule and I would like my planning vim document to output the subjects that I have on that specific day.

```
[["English", "Maths", "Digitech"],["Science", "Maths", "English"],["blah"],[],[],[],[]] //From monday to sunday
```

What is the best way to get the day of the week and is it possible to run external python scripts/etc so I can maybe get the day of the week and output data from there.

Thanks!!

Comment: Google is your friend. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Kent's answer will print the day of the week, but if you want to insert it into your file, you need something a little bit more complicated:

```
:nnoremap <F5> "=strftime("%w")<CR>P
```

Then you can use `F5` to insert the date.  You could do this with a Python script:

```
import time

print(time.strftime("%w"))
```

Then in `vim`, do this:

```
:r !python myscript.py
```

Answer (score 2):

vim's `strftime()` function can help you to get this, simply:

```
strftime("%w")
```

If I run `:echo strftime("%w")` on today (2016-03-31 Thursday), I got `4` returned on my system.

`:h strftime(` for details.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
import datetime
weekdayToday=datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
```